# Fast way (vectorization?) to apply a list of functions to corresponding columns in a data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I have a named list of variable length, containing functions

```
mFunc <- list(A = identity, B = exp)
```

I also have a `data.frame` which names are a superset of the names of `mFunc`:

```
dat <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 1:3, C = 1:3)
```

What I want to do is to apply all functions in `mFunc` to the corresponding columns in `dat`. If I would do it by hand, I would do

```
dat$A <- mFunc$A(dat$A)
dat$B <- mFunc$B(dat$B)
```

and the expected results would be:

```
#   A         B C
# 1 1  2.718282 1
# 2 2  7.389056 2
# 3 3 20.085537 3
```

I was thinking of using a loop on the names of `mFunc`

```
library(plyr)
dat[, names(mFunc)] <- llply(names(mFunc), function(n) mFunc[[n]](dat[[n]]))
```

which gives me the desired result. I was wondering whether there are faster (vectorized) ways of doing that without using an implicit loop?

Comment: How about make one function that switches to different functions based on passed column name?

Comment: Looping over columns should be efficient enough. I don't think you can vectorize it in any better way, as you have different functions that need to be evaluated. Though I don't understand why are you using `plyr`. Why not just `dat[, names(mFunc)] <- lapply(names(mFunc), function(x) mFunc[[x]](dat[[x]]))`? Another way could be to use `mapply` such as `dat[, names(mFunc)] <- mapply(function(x, y) x(y), mFunc, dat[, names(mFunc)])`

Comment: I use `plyr` because I like the concept that you can control input and output of your `apply` function. Base `R` has similar functions, but I found the `plyr` functions more readable and easier to switch from one to another. Without the context I agree with you that `lapply` is doing exactly the same, but in the rest of my code I am using all sorts of `??ply` and I like to use verbs from the same family.

Comment: I was trying to say that of you are looking for optimization, then `plyr` is probably not the way. I would bet `lapply` will be much more efficient than `llply` on a big data set.

Comment: See my answer on the speed comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Benchmark**

Following up on the discussion, I did some benchmark with the `llply` and the `lapply` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(microbenchmark)

makeTestData <- function(n, m = 10) {
   ret <- matrix(1, m, n)
   as.list(as.data.frame(ret))
}

d1e7 <- makeTestData(1e7)
d1e6 <- makeTestData(1e6)
d1e5 <- makeTestData(1e5)
d1e4 <- makeTestData(1e4)

(mb <- microbenchmark(dplyr_1e7 = llply(d1e7,  sum),
                      base__1e7 = lapply(d1e7, sum),
                      dplyr_1e6 = llply(d1e6,  sum),
                      base__1e6 = lapply(d1e6, sum),
                      dplyr_1e5 = llply(d1e5,  sum),
                      base__1e5 = lapply(d1e5, sum),
                      dplyr_1e4 = llply(d1e4,  sum),
                      base__1e4 = lapply(d1e4, sum),
                      unit = "s"))

#  Unit: seconds
#       expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval  cld
#  dplyr_1e7 0.516720538 0.589467527 0.684496553 0.626970606 0.713114314 1.50305854   100    d
#  base__1e7 0.510537527 0.568317076 0.650109031 0.593912047 0.654385189 1.65846752   100   cd
#  dplyr_1e6 0.498767583 0.574463177 0.678273933 0.614690247 0.695204388 1.22767911   100    d
#  base__1e6 0.490427644 0.543392591 0.610153445 0.587542713 0.638059997 1.03797757   100   c 
#  dplyr_1e5 0.045505505 0.047664210 0.076620745 0.049840086 0.062213015 0.83327188   100  b  
#  base__1e5 0.043557401 0.046385212 0.079063845 0.050644790 0.079270672 0.54647818   100  b  
#  dplyr_1e4 0.004488338 0.004746704 0.005941600 0.004970133 0.005845892 0.03784612   100 a   
#  base__1e4 0.004290173 0.004527419 0.006759915 0.004698939 0.005140864 0.04752546   100 a
```

And some statistics:

```
mb %>% group_by(expr) %>% summarise(mean = mean(time)) %>%
   separate(expr, c("system", "size"), sep = "\\_+") %>%
   spread(system, mean) %>% mutate(ratio = base / dplyr)   

# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

#    size      base     dplyr     ratio
#   (chr)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
# 1   1e4   6759915   5941600 1.1377262
# 2   1e5  79063845  76620745 1.0318856
# 3   1e6 610153445 678273933 0.8995679
# 4   1e7 650109031 684496553 0.9497623
```

**Conclusion**

So, the `base`solution is 6% faster for big data sets and 13% slower(!) for small data sets. Absolute the execution times for both are of the same magnitude. Hence, I can accept the small delay (even if present: not noticeable for me anyways) for using the same family of verbs.

Comment: Percent is a relative thing. Being slower on a small data set by 13% won't be felt. While being slower on big data sets even by few percent would be felt much more. Though in this specific case there is no big difference. But this was pretty much my point that your solution should be efficient enough.

Comment: Sure, 99% on 1ms is negligible, vs. 0.1% on a year makes a huge difference - agreed. So I was wondering in general, why you think that `lapply` will be *<quote>much more efficient</quote>* than `llply`?

Comment: Because `llply` is a wrapper.